# pandas data frame time stamp colum find value from another rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and need help…
I have a dataframe that has 2 columns:
Timestamp: a column containing timestamp like 2008-07-07 11:30:25
And column A that contains 0 or 1 of type int.
I need to find for every row if there one or more rows in the dataframe with timestamp bigger than the row's timestamp and the gap between the time stamps is less than 20 minutes and the row with bigger timestamp has in column A the value 1. I must add new column res to the dataframe containing 0 or 1 for every row
Example:

If the data frame looks like

```
Timestamp            A

2008-07-07 11:30:25  0

2008-07-07 11:35:25  1
```

I need the result dataframe to be:

```
Timestamp            A  Res

2008-07-07 11:30:25  0  1

2008-07-07 11:35:25  1  0
```

I tried using the apply method:

i called to_datetime method:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```

then I wrote a method:

```
def f(ts, df):
    d = len(df[(df['A'] == 1) & ((df['Timestamp'] - ts).seconds <300))]
    df.res= len(d) > 0
```

then I called

```
 df.Timestamp.apply(lambda ts: f(ts,df))
```

but it does not work.. it say I can't apply seconds to a series

please help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

First check the dtypes of the data frame. Make sure that it is not of str format. Also in the function you defined there is error df['A'] (you did not close the ' after A.

Comment: thanks i copied the code by hand... so i missed the '. also i called to_datetime... that didnt fix the error

Comment: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'seconds' . Use 'x.second' and not 'x.seconds'

Comment: ts is the parmeter which is sent to the lambda expression. it is the value of the timestamp in every row in the data frame

Comment: but ts is no where defined in your code.                                                  
ts = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Timestamp']) should be defined something like this to use

Comment: ts refers to the value of Timestamp colum. See apply method.

Answer (score 0):

[image: check the code here hope that helps]

check the code from screenshot hope that helps